# Variable not accessible when declared in the Page_Load method

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i declare a variable, lets say

```
public string [] companiesArray = {"Google","BBC","CNN","SportsDirect","Microsoft"};
```

just after public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page, the variable is accessible, but when i declare the variable in the Page_Load method, the variable is not accessible.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string [] companiesArray = {"Google","BBC","CNN","SportsDirect","Microsoft"};
    }
```

What could be the problem? Could some one help me out please.

Comment: Well it's a local variable, so it's only accessible within `Page_Load`. Why would you *expect* it to be accessible anywhere else?

Comment: It's common concept of Public,Private,Protected access modifier.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Andrei accessible within any other method that i call it.

Comment: @JonSkeet so how do i make it to be global?

Comment: @MutieMule - I think you need to learn about the difference between class member variables and method variables, specifically their difference in scope.

Comment: @MutieMule: Well you've already seen how to do it - you declare it as an instance variable. I suggest you put down ASP.NET for the moment and go back the the basics of C#, ideally via console apps (where there isn't any baggage of UIs, servers etc). Then once you're confident in the core language, you'll have a better idea of how to move on to ASP.NET

Comment: @MutieMule - go read any of Jon Skeet's books on C#, well worth your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand about scope.

When you define the array in the page, you are defining the scope to be the class. You can use the variable anywhere within the class.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   string[] companiesArray;

    public void DoFizz()
    {
        companiesArray[0] = "Fizz";
    }

    public void DoBuzz()
    {
        companiesArray[1] = "Buzz";
    }
}
```

When you define it in page load, then the scope is limited to that method, so you can only use it within that method.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] companiesArray;
    }
}
```

One of the major advantages of this, is if you declare variables within methods, it stops you accidentaly using a variable that may have been defined and used elsewhere. If this were not the case you wouldn't be able to guarantee the state of your variable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So how do i declare the variable to be global?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want a global variable. If you define it within the class scope and make it public, then you will have access to it throughout the class (all the methods), and from other place which can reference that class.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare the variable inside the `Page_load` it is a **local** variable for that **scope**.

If you declare the variable after `public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page`

it is a **global** variable for all the Page.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)

If a variable is defined within your `Page_Load` method, then it is local to that method

If you defined it outside of the method, it's visible to the rest of the code, and is typically refered to as a [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), e.g.

```
public partial class Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private string[] companiesArray = {"Google","BBC","CNN","SportsDirect","Microsoft"};
   public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //companiesArray  is visible here
   }

   public void SomeOtherMethod()
   {
      //companiesArray is visible here too
   }
}
```